# Convert a PDF/Word title page to TEX file

Tags: pdf, titles

Is there any way I can convert a PDF containing a title page like the following into a working TEX file?

I have tried different converters like AbiWord or Grindeq, but the result never works properly. I could also use a Word to TEX converter if the result was really accurate. In this case, format is important, as the result has to be identical to the PDF shown.

[image]

Comment: So, you want to include this PDF into an existing tex file, but you need to change the contents of the PDF (like title, name etc)?

Comment: Yes. I would like to make a tex file where I can change those fields and results in that format. It is for a thesis.

Comment: you should be able to get vector or high resolution versions of the  two images from your institution, and after that it's just a simple page of centred text, so conversion from Word (or anything) is likely just to produce an over-complicated result.

Comment: The problem is that it has to be exactly the same title page, because of format requirements. Otherwise it is likely to be rejected. Is there no way this can be done without requiring to a manual solution?

Comment: Can't the institute / tutor provide a template for the title page.

Comment: Use Word to create the title page you want and output to PDF. Then include the PDF as a graphic in your TeX file

Comment: What Peter said makes the most sense. See also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Answer (score 1):

To copy the layout of this page using LaTeX you need the two logos as files, jpeg or png will do. And you need the font.

The layout of the page isn't sophisticated. There are many ways to do that with LaTeX. To put the logos to the right place, take a ruler and measure the distance from the margin and then use the package eso-pic and two `\put` commands. Insert the lines using `\vspace` for exact distances. If you are in trouble, ask a new question and provide an MWE.

Another way may be to get a software to change the PDF-template. Probably that can be done with something like [Master PDF editor](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/)